# Gronwall's Inequality with RHS absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Wikipedia states Gronwall's inequality (simplest case on compact domain) as follows. Let $u$ and $\beta$ be continuous on $I=[a,b]$ with $\beta$ continuous on $I$. If $u$ is differentiable on $I^{0}$, the interior of $I$, and satifies the differential inequality
\begin{align} \label{eqn:first}
u'(t) \leq \beta(t) u(t),
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
u(t) \leq u(a) exp\left(\int_{a}^{t} \beta(s) ds\right).
\end{align}

What happens if I replace the right-hand side of my differential inequality with $|u(t)|$? That is, change none of the assumptions to the theorem except for weakening the inequality to
\begin{align}
u'(t) \leq \beta(t) \color{red}{|u(t)|}.
\end{align}
**My question: if I change only the absolute value term in red above, does the conclusion**
\begin{align}
u(t) \leq u(a) exp\left(\int_{a}^{t} \beta(s)ds\right)
\end{align}
**still hold?**

**For further context:** In my lecture notes for proving continuous dependence for simple ODE, we used a Lipschitz bound to derive the differential inequality
\begin{align}
E'(t) &\leq L |E(t)| \\
E(0) &= \epsilon
\end{align}
for some constant $L$. Then apply Gronwall's inequality. My concern with this has to do with the fact that $|u(t)|$ is not necessarily differentiable if I were to have $u(t)=0$. At that point, I am violating the assumptions of Gronwall's lemma.

Comment: $|u|$ is not differentiable if $u(t)=0$.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to weaken the assumption of Gronwall's inequality. The usual Gronwall's inequality cannot be applied directly to conclude the answer to my question.

Comment: Direct application would lead to the differentiability issue that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for the conclusion of the Bellman Gronwall lemma is incorrect, it should read $u(t) \le u(a) e^{\int_a^t \beta(s)ds}$.

Choose $\beta = 1, a=0, u(t) = -1-t$.

Then $u'(t) = -1$, and $u'(t) \le \beta |u(t)|$, but the conclusion would read
$u(t) = -1-t \le (-1) e^t$ which is clearly violated for a finite value of $t>a$.

**Aside**:
It is not clear what 'continuous dependence' means in your question, but one nice approach to proving continuity is to show, under appropriate assumptions, that the fixed point solution of an operator $P_y$ (that is, the solution to $x = P_y(x)$) is continuously dependent (in a prescribed sense) on the parameter $y$.

Such an approach can be found in Functional Analysis, 2nd Ed. by Kantorovich & Alikov, ch. XVI, Section 1, Theorem 3 (continuity of fixed point) and
ch. XVI, Section 4, Theorem 1 (continuity of solution of ODE on initial condition).

Comment: Great thanks. This counterexample is simple. And the sense of continuous dependence I was looking at is the sense of your second source, continuity w.r.t. initial conditions.